# Visual Studio Setup Failed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vs-community-edition

My Windows 10 computer had an update. Right after the update, Visual Studio stopped working so I tried reinstalling it. Now it will not even install. I tried installing it many times but all it says is,

> "Setup Failed! Install cannot continue because some required
>   components failed."

I tried looking online about this problem but I couldn't find a solution. I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me with this problem since I really want to program. Thank you!

[[image: Visual Studio Error Screenshot][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Ou1.png)

Comment: Open Log file and check the errors.

Comment: please omit the installation file and download the webinstaller from internet then you will install the VS2015 in your system